# QTreeView: maintaining mapping between QModelIndex and underlying data

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I have problems migrating from `QTreeWidget` to `QtreeView`. Things that were obvious and trivial with `QTreeWidget` seem to be impossible with view. Specifically: I have a main window with a treeview in it. TreeView uses the model I've implemented, but not directly – through `QSortFilterProxyModel` that is set as a tree's model. Now, the user activates an item in the tree and main windows receives a signal `itemActivated(QModelIndex item)`. How can I tell which item of the underlying data was activated? Data is a vector, so with TreeWidget I could just store an item's vector index in the `QTreeWidgetItem`, but `QModelIndex` doesn’t even have `setData` API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define custom roles in your source model, returning the underlying data or an identifier (if there's one) as variant. This has the advantage it works with any number of proxy models in between, as the data will be passed through the models unaltered and now mapping of indexes is required.

Assuming a model listing contacts, with a value struct/class `Contact` holding the data.
This requires `Contact` to be registered via `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`.

```
class ContactModel ... {
    ...

    enum Role {
        ContactRole=Qt::UserRole,
        ContactIdRole
    };

    QVariant data(...) const {
        ...
        const Contact& contact = ...get from datastructure...
        ...
        switch (role) {
        ...
        case ContactRole:
             return QVariant::fromValue( contact );
        case ContactIdRole:
             return contact.id;
        }
    }
    ...
```

And in the code receiving the index:

```
void SomeWidget::indexSelected(const QModelIndex& index)
{
    const int id = index.data(ContactModel::ContactIdRole).toInt();
    // look up Contact, do something with it

    //or:

    const Contact contact = index.data(ContactModel::ContactRole).value<Contact>();
    // do something with the contact

    ...
}
```

The index can be from the contact model itself, or any proxy on top of it - the code here doesn't have to care.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I tell which item of the underlying data was activated?

By inverting the proxy model:

```
// supposing to connect this to your itemActivated signal
void onItemActivated(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    QModelIndex originalIndex = proxyModel->mapToSource(index);
    originalModel->doSomething(originalIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The model to stores your data. The data is no longer owned by items/`QModelIndex` in the view. `QModelIndex` is only a unique identifier passed between the view and the model (in this case via `QSortFilterProxyModel`). The model should inherit `QAbstractItemModel` which has some pure virtual functions that need to be defined (you can copy boilerplate from http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-simpletreemodel.html). You will e.g. have to define `QAbstractItemModel::data( const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole)` which defines which data that corresponds to a particular `QModelIndex`.

The QSortFilterProxyModel sits between the view and the model, but does not change the principles for the model. See the other answer on this question for how to deal with the `QModelIndex` conversion.

To conclude: `QAbstractItemModel::data( const QModelIndex & index)` will give you the data for a particular `QModelIndex` once you have defined it.