# How to map the QListWidget / QStandardItemModel item to my logic?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel, qtwidgets

**Quick question**

Is there an easy/quick way to map a `QListWidget` or `QStandardItemModel` (for `QListView`) item to my application logic?

**Complete Question**

> Note: I will use undistinctly both `QListWidget` or QListView and itsQStandardItemModel. From my current point of view for this question, switching from one to another is trivial.

I face usually the need to have a `QListView` or equivalent in an HMI, which shows some text value and need to react on selection/click.

In the `SLOT`, in order to perform the required action, the row need to be identified. `Qt::DisplayRole` is NOT appropriate because some texts could be duplicated and QStrings are not the best way to identify data in Computer Science.

```
// Click on a row
connect( &myView, &QListView::clicked, 
[&myView, this]( const QModelIndex &idx)
{
    // E.G. need to update the database for this row.  Which row?
});
```

Possible solutions:

- Maintain a `map` to retrieve the ID from the `QModelIndex` row.
- Save in the model row any ID, making easy to apply any operation.

First option is tedious: it requires to connect the model for keeping the map and the model synchronized.. Same logic again and again.

Second option seem by far the best: I save the (e.g. database id) and use it afterward; But, `QListView` model (up to what I know) does NOT include this very friendly and useful ID. So until now I had extended again and again the models for `QListView`.

How to map the QModelIndex back to my application logic? Do I really have to extend the model for that simple operation?

> RELATED QUESTION: [QTreeView: maintaining mapping between QModelIndex and underlying data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941701/qtreeview-maintaining-mapping-between-qmodelindex-and-underlying-data)

Answer (score 1):

What about creating the QAbstractModel manually, this way you have complete control how the QModelIndexes are created, and you can use that to do stuff.

I'v implemented thousands of Qt Models, and I have never liked the QStandardItemModel approach as I would usually need to write more boilerplate than if I had come with the model myself.

- Inherit from your QAbstractList/Table/TreeModel
- implement index()
- create a method for direct item access

.

```
// Click on a row
connect( &myView, &QListView::clicked, 
[&myView, this]( const QModelIndex &idx)
{
   auto& myItem = idx.model()->directAccess(idx.row());
});
```

- profit.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing ("So until now I had extended again and again the models for QListView"). I wonder if there is a predefined `role`, some hidden behavior or whatever else that avoid me to implement this QAbstractItemModel, so I could re-use all the normal QStandardItemModel stuff.

Comment: I created a QObjectListModel that holds a QList<QObject*> and I'm using it everywhere, using the Q_PROPERTIES to populate things on the table (one column per peroperty).

Comment: Absolutely, if there is no easier way, I will have to create/maintain a Model with similar behavior. Probably some template model, so the content is easy to set.

Comment: template wont work - it's a QObject after all. moc needs to run on it. I would go for a QVariantModel or a QObjectModel, it's easy to deal with QObject pointers.

Comment: Mmm, templates seem to works pretty fine, QAbstractItemModel is not a QObject. Or did you meant the QListView?

Comment: QAbstractItemModel inhertits from QObject, for sure.

Comment: so what is the issue with templating QAbstractItemModel? I just did it and up to now it seem to works.

Comment: There's a good response for that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238204/is-it-possible-to-mix-template-derived-c-classes-with-qts-q-object